# Apache 2.2 conf file multiple directives

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, timeout

I have an infrastructure on AWS, and yesterday, it presented intermittence with the message that CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but was unable to.
Apparently, but I think it has nothing to do with that, the httpd.conf directives Timeout and ProxyTimeout resolved the issue by setting their values to 10 times the normal value of 60 seconds.

The problem was with a particular web context that already had connectiontimeout=180 timeout=180 properties:

> ProxyPass ajp://192.168.70.35:8009/auctions connectiontimeout=180 timeout=180
>     ProxyPassReverse ajp://192.168.70.35:8009/auctions

Now the probable solution was to append

> Timeout 600
>
> ProxyTimeout 600

to the file, but I realize the beginning of the file already has a Timeout property set to 60.

So my question is, how does apache reads this file in the case two Timeout directives are set with different values? Does it read the first value but stays with the last and behaves this way?

Of course I know it should only have one directive, but we are investigating the root cause of the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: This answer here could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152943/how-can-i-view-the-complete-httpd-configuration#27155469 . That is - it could possibly show you what apache thinks it is configured like.

Answer (score 0):

Timeout and ProxyTimeout are different directives. ProxyTimeout is for when you're using apache to forward request to another server/application. It tells apache how long to wait for the second server to respond.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxytimeout

It doesn't sound like it applies to your setup, Timeout is the only one you need to change.

Comment: All right, thanks! So, if the file has two Timeout directives, which one is gonna use? The one at the beginning or the one at the end?

Comment: You're welcome, sorry I didn't see that part of your question. Apache always takes the last value set for any directive. It's also good to check that the directive isn't being changed in any other config files that are processed afterwards.